# How to define the number of levels in a hierarchy using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

My situation is the following. I have a table containing a product hierarchy. The following table is an extract of the dataset:

```
child    parent
  1        2
  2        3
  4        5
  6        7
```

I want to add a column containing the depth (of the child) of the hierarchy. Something as follows:

```
child    parent   depth
  1        2        2
  2        3        1
  4        5        1
  6        7        1
```

How would I do that in oracle? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using at least 11g R2? Then a recursive *Common Table Expression* (CTE) is possible

Comment: Why does the first row and second rows have a depth of 3 and 2 respectively? Should they not have a depth of 2 and 1?

Comment: You're right concerning the depth. I changed it. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT child, parent, level
FROM   your_table
START WITH parent NOT IN ( SELECT child FROM your_table )
CONNECT BY parent = PRIOR child;
```

Outputs:

```
CHILD PARENT LEVEL
----- ------ -----
    1      2     2
    2      3     1
    4      5     1
    6      7     1
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Thank you. Where does the level come from in your select?

Comment: @PatrickBalada The [`LEVEL` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009261) is generated by the hierarchical query.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!